# EasyPhp: How to Enable Openssl

Tags: openssl, phpmailer, email, easyphp

Hi how can I enable openssl in Easyphp as Im getting the error Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: Extension missing: opensslTime: when using phpmailer. Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306). (And this question has been asked 10's or 100's of times).

Comment: Im using php's mail function on a localhost  and went through the torment of getting it to work.  Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your `php.ini`

Change

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

and restart your web server.